# What is the most appropriate SWT widget in which to enter a Long value?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I currently have a JFace Wizard page containing several SWT Spinners to allow a user to enter positive numerical values. Because a Spinner is backed by integers, the maximum limit is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I would like to allow users to enter positive whole numbers greater than that.

I don't know of any SWT widget that is backed by a `long`. One possible solution I thought of was to use a `Text` widget and attach a VerifyListener, which will do something like this:

```
public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
     e.doit = e.text.matches("[0-9]+");
     try {
         new Long(e.text);
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
         e.doit = false;
     }
}
```

Is there a better way to allow a user to enter a value larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Answer (score 2):

Spinners are generally useful, when you enter small values of integers. Even for bigger values of integers, a text box (with a validator like yours) is more preferred than a spinner. I guess you are on the right path.